# Charging problem in lineageOS 17.1 galaxy J7 elte

Tags: samsung, custom-roms, charging, lineageos, samsung-galaxy-j7

I have installed lineageOS 17.1 on galaxy J7 elte. Charging speed is very low. First time I plugged the charger, in 87% charging stoped and second time in 80%. It was showing charging symbol in the status bar but charging was stoped. How can I repair this problem?

***NOTE: I have rooted lineage with magisk.***

Comment: It seems that you use an unofficial LineageOS version as Galaxy J7 is not in the official list of supported devices. As always with third party developer custom ROMs problems may occur. Best contact the author of the used custom ROM.

Comment: I downloaded it from http://lineageosroms.com/j7elte. Is not it official?

Comment: The official download site from LineageOS is https://download.lineageos.org LineageOS has already dropped support of most devices of your age so I don't know who is operating the site you got your ROM from (only a twitter contact is mentioned which is a bit shady).

Comment: So I can't find the developer. I ask others to help me. Thank you